# Append value to each sublist in a list

Tags: python

I have a list of list that I want to append a constant value to each sublist of the full list, for instance:

```
_lst = [[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]]
```

and I want to append `7` to each of the sublist so that `_lst` becomes:

```
[[1, 2, 7], [3, 4, 7], [5, 6, 7]]
```

Is there a good way to complete the job (such as using `zip`)? Thanks!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
for l in _lst:
    l.append(7)
```

Comment: I personally prefer the explicitness of this answer. It also lends itself to further actions on `l` while it iterates.

Answer (score 6):

```
_lst = [ele + [7] for ele in _lst]
```

Comment: @Rock, you don't need to use `zip` here, what do you want to do with `zip`?

Comment: Besides, this code creates a new list, leaving `_lst` unchanged.

Comment: You are right. I made a cosmetic change so my resulting list is called `_lst`, but I do create a new list and then just call it `_lst`, while you perform a change on the original list.

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> tmp = [ i.append(7) for i in _lst ]
>>> print _lst
[[1, 2, 7], [3, 4, 7], [5, 6, 7]]
```

Comment: While this'll work, using a listcomp for side effect purposes like this is usually disfavoured: it creates an intermediate list consisting of `None`s and then throws it away.